# AngularJS: Splicing scope array removes entire ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I am writing an AngularJS app that contains a $scope array which I populate a ul with.  Each li contains an "x" which when clicked calls a function in my Chatroom controller and removes the item from the $scope array.

What should happen is that the item is removed from the array and hence also from the view. But if I step through the debugger I can visually see the li being removed from the DOM, but afterwards my entire ng-view gets removed.

Images here:

[Before clicking "x"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oyvf.png)

[After clicking "x"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYMtV.png)

I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this.  I shall post code below.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="chatasticExtension" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load    bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div> 
</body>

<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-   animate.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/socket-io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/constants/configs.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/socket-factory.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/authentication.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/chrome-tabs-manager.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/chatroom.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/tabs.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/header.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/rooms-lists-tabs.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/chat-window.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/ng-enter.js"></script>

</html>
```

main.html (This is what is displayed in ng-view and what disappears)

```
<div class="container main-container" ng-controller="ChatroomCtrl" >
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <rooms-lists-tabs></rooms-lists-tabs>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <chat-window ng-hide="!activeConversation"></chat-window>
    </div>
</div>
```

rooms-lists-tabs.html (Note the ng-click="leaveRoom($index) on the second ng-repeat for convo in conversations)

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
<uib-tab index="0" heading="{{tabs[0].name}}">
    <div class="scrollable-container list-group">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="room in rooms" ng-click="joinRoom(room.url)">{{ room.title }}</a>
    </div>
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab index="1" heading="{{tabs[1].name}}">
    <div class="scrollable-container list-group">
        <a id="a-{{urlToId(convo.url)}}" href="" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="convo in conversations" ng-click="switchConversation(convo.url)">
            {{ convo.title }}
            <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="leaveRoom($index)"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</uib-tab>
```

Chatroom Controller (leaveRoom function only)

```
$scope.leaveRoom = function(index) {
    var conversation = $scope.conversations[index];

    socket.emit("leaveRoom", {
        user: $scope.user,
        room: conversation.url
    });
    $scope.conversations.splice(index, 1);
}

/**
     * Sets the activeConversation to a conversation in the conversations array that matches the passed in url.
     * @param url
     */
    $scope.switchConversation = function(url) {
        if($scope.activeConversation && $scope.activeConversation.url === url) {
            return;
        }

        var conversation = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.conversations.length; i++) {
            if($scope.conversations[i].url === url) {
                conversation = $scope.conversations[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(conversation) {
            $scope.activeConversation = conversation;
        }
        else {
            // If the conversation was not found, add the conversation and try to switch again
            addNewConversation(url);
            $scope.switchConversation(url); // Possible infinite loop here if addNewConversation fails somehow.
        }
    };
```

Please let me know if you wish to see other pieces of code.

Thanks

UPDATE: As per Gary's suggestion, I tried using pop(). pop() works until I pop the very last item in the list at which point the entire ng-view will disappear again.

UPDATE 2: If I switch to the first tab right after I splice, I never get the error.

UPDATE 3: Added switchConversation function

Comment: @Gary Hmmm...interesting.  Pop() actually works right up until I remove the very last item at which point the entire ng-view is removed again.

Comment: Can you please add any fiddle/plnkr?

Comment: I would also like to see plunkr to see what is happening. Can you add it in? Possibly it will do what you are facing/doing unless you keep a default un-deletable tab. Or you need to handle what to do after deleting the last tab, say route to a different location or not allow deleting it.

Comment: Show code for `switchConversation` function.

Comment: @Stepan I added the switchConversation function.  I'm trying to get plunker working...but it's not easy to transfer all the necessary parts to get it working.

Comment: We are waiting plunker)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by the following way which I will explain in your case.

Add $event to your ng-click function i.e., ng-click="leaveRoom($event,$index)"

and now your leave room function should be like below

```
$scope.leaveRoom = function(event,index) {
    var conversation = $scope.conversations[index];

    socket.emit("leaveRoom", {
        user: $scope.user,
        room: conversation.url
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.conversations.splice(index, 1);
};
```

This will only remove whatever index you selected